# Disable Quasar's default CSS

Tags: quasar-framework

Is there any way to disable the default `quasar.css` which comes with a Quasar app?

It's almost 12000 lines long and I don't plan on using any of it. I can't find anything which mentions how you could do this, so I'm assuming it can't be done.

Comment: It is a strange request, since it is part of the quasar core, however consider that if you use the quasar components you will need the quasar css, otherwise it would only be vue.js

Comment: I'm only really using Quasar for its integration across platforms. I don't plan on using any of the components

Comment: I understand, you have 3 options: 1. handle it independently of quasar, that is to say with electron, cordova or capacitor. 2. use it with quasar and remove the styles from the generated files or place your complete code in the folders to read the files from. 3. analyze the quasar code of the webpack and identify where it adds the file "import 'quasar / dist / quasar.sass'" and comment it. I assume your problem is that the styles intersect with some library you are using. If you can solve it, comment how you did it in case someone else has the same problem

Comment: I think you're right. I'll do some tweaking and see what I can figure out. Thanks, @ManuelTemple

Comment: Seems there isn't any decent way around this and I've noticed a couple of other issues with Quasar, so I'm switching to Nuxt and implementing Electron/Capacitor separately

Answer (score 2):

The solution I've got is for `quasar v2`, but I am pretty sure it should work with `v1` too.

The end result is straighforward:

```
// quasar.config.js
build: {
  chainWebpack (chain) {
    chain.resolve.alias.set('quasar/dist/quasar.css', false)
    chain.resolve.alias.set('quasar/dist/quasar.prod.css', false)

    chain.module.rule('sass').exclude.add(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.sass'))
    chain.module.rule('scss').exclude.add(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.scss'))
  }
}
```

The `chain.resolve.alias.set` is taking care of `import 'quasar/dist/quasar.css'` in the `.quasar/client-entry.js` file. For a further explanation see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias

> Setting resolve.alias to false will tell webpack to ignore a module.

The `chain.module.rule` part disables processing of `sass/scss`. Note that `../../node_modules` path will need amending if you don't use `workspaces` (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces or https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/).

Make sure to delete `quasar.variables.(sass|scss)` so quasar doesn't try to load it's css.

Note: don't use `IgnorePlugin` as the imported module will be removed during the build (see https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2858)

Another note: I only tested this in SPA mode, but will update the answer if I come across any problems while testing other modes.

Comment: Awesome work finding this.

Comment: When I do this I get `ReferenceError: path is not defined`

Comment: You need to use node.js path module. Add the following at the top of the config file  `const path = require('path')`

Answer (score 0):

```
//quasar.conf.js Quasar plugins
 
plugins: [],
removeDefaultCss: true
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the how is important, but a great part of the level of quality comes from the fact that people go to great lengths to explain the why. While a code-only answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)

Comment: Your answer is based on PR which was not implemented -> https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/8272